# C# Xamarin Android . ButtonClick event help needed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tired doing a simple A+B addition program using xamarin but every time error system.NullReferenceException occurs for Button click.

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += delegate {
            EditText number1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText number2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
            TextView res = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            int result = Convert.ToInt32(number1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(number2.Text);
            res.Text = result.ToString();
        };
```

[image]

Comment: You have not set the activity content `SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You commented out the line:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

This "binds" the current activity to the content view.
If you dont bind that your program cant find any elements like your button. So it gives you a object reference error.

So remove the // infront of the SetContentView and it should work.

Comment: Hi sorry Your solution worked and restart did it :) thanks a lot